# getting error on browser refresh using cookies in python

Tags: python, html, cgi

Here is my form.html

```
form name="form1" action="/cgi-bin/form2.py" method="post"
input type="text" name="firstname"
input type="submit" value="submit"
```

and below is my form2.py

```
import cgi
print 'Content-type:text/html\n\n'
cookie=Cookie.SimpleCookie()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
searchterm = form["firstname"].value
print 'Set-Cookie: lastvisit=' + str(searchterm)
cookie["firstname"]=searchterm
print "firstname="+ cookie["firstname"].value
cookie_string = os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE')
if not cookie_string:
      print '<p>First visit or cookies disabled</p>'
 else: 
      print '<p>The returned cookie string was "' + cookie_string + '"</p>'
cookie.load(cookie_string)
lastvisit = float(cookie['lastvisit'].value)
cookie['lastvisit']['path'] = '/var/www/cgi-bin/'
print searchterm
print 'Content-type:text/html\n\n'
print "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5'>"
```

we have a form.html and form2.py files, from form.html i am submitting firstname to form2.py after submitting i am getting the 'searchterm' value, then i am refreshing the browser after refresh i am getting `<type 'exceptions.keyerror'>:firstname`.
even though i have set and retrive the cookie value i am unable to refresh the browser using cookie value.
Please help me i am facing this problem from past 4 days.

Thanks,
Vittal.

Comment: Well, the fact that the HTML seems to reference a script called `sa2.py`, whereas you say you code is in `form2.py` might be worth looking at.

Comment: sorry type mistake, its action="/cgi-bin/form2.py" only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my guess is correct, first you are clicking on submit button, then it is redirecting to form2.py ( i.e. form.html is submitting value to form2.py so the value form["firstname"].value exists). Now you are refreshing on form2.py which in turn not sending any value as there is no submit. Refreshing does not mean submitting it is just loading the current page

form2.py is not submitting any data, then how the value form["firstname"].value exists

Comment: Thanks for the response, what you have said is correct, but my requirement is to get the form value upon refreshing the form2.py. So how to do it. Please suggest me its my requirement.

Comment: use GET method if security is not issue 

for ex:  /form2.py?firstname="somevalue"

Comment: form name="form1" action="/cgi-bin/form2.py?firstname=somevalue"

Comment: Can i put any value in place of 'somevalue', in the above code.

Comment: NO its not working.Now i am getting another error, error is 'list' object has no attribute 'value'. it is showing error at line searchterm = form['firstname'].value